# c++ COUT operator precedence

Tags: c++

I was trying out some random programs to strengthen my basic knowlege. I executed 2 statements:

```
int i = 4;
cout<<i++*i++;  //returned 16
cout<<i++*++i;  //returned 25
```

Can I please get an explanation of what is happening behind the scene?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is [undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points), there is no determinant output.

Comment: ... plus this is not about the cout operator precedence, but about the ++ operator.